# Can't find the AT content in percentage (tkinter, classes)

Tags: python, bioinformatics

relatively new to Python programming and attempting to get this program to work.

The tkinter interface launches properly and everything but once I hit calculate it is meant to spit out a percentage value of the A + T letters / total length of the string you enter, in the console but I keep running into errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *


class AT_content_calculator:

    def dna_sequence(self):
        self.dna_sequence = ()

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame_1 = Frame(master, width=700, height=700)
        frame_1.pack()
        frame_1.pack_propagate()

        self.entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=self.dna_sequence)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.button_1 = Button(frame_1, text="Calculate", command=self.at_calculate)
        self.button_1.pack()
        self.button_2 = Button(frame_1, text="Quit", command=frame_1.quit)
        self.button_2.pack()

    def at_calculate(self):

        self.total_bases = len(self.dna_sequence)
        self.a_bases = self.dna_sequence.count("A")
        self.b_bases = self.dna_sequence.count("T")
        self.at_content = (self.a_bases + self.b_bases) / self.total_bases
        print(self.at_content)

root = Tk()
b = AT_content_calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add, this line before `self.total_bases = len(self.dna_sequence)`

```
self.dna_sequence = self.entry_1.get()
```

you get:

[image: output form]

**EDIT**

try:

```
from tkinter import *

class AT_content_calculator:

    def dna_sequence(self):
        self.dna_sequence = ()

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame_1 = Frame(master, width=700, height=700)
        frame_1.pack()
        frame_1.pack_propagate()
        self.entry_1 = Entry(frame_1)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.varoutput_1 = StringVar()
        self.output_1 = Label(frame_1, textvariable=self.varoutput_1)
        self.output_1.pack()
        self.button_1 = Button(frame_1, text="Calculate", command=self.at_calculate)
        self.button_1.pack()
        self.button_2 = Button(frame_1, text="Quit", command=frame_1.quit)
        self.button_2.pack()

    def at_calculate(self):
        self.dna_sequence = self.entry_1.get()
        self.total_bases = len(self.dna_sequence)
        self.a_bases = self.dna_sequence.count("A")
        self.b_bases = self.dna_sequence.count("T")
        self.at_content = (self.a_bases + self.b_bases) / self.total_bases
        print(self.at_content)
        self.varoutput_1.set(self.at_content)

root = Tk()
b = AT_content_calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

you get:

[image: output 2]

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thanks. Any pointers on how to get that number into the tkinter interface? Say below the Calculate button.